# How do I 'share' pieces of code throughout my whole app?

Tags: objective-c

I am working on a simple app. This app has various textfields that require the 'Done' button in a toolbar.

Currently, this toolbar requires <10 lines of code, but I dislike the fact that for every textfield in every viewController I need to add those lines.

So, is there a way to shorten this 'toolbar setup'? Ideally, I would need to call a single method containing all I need:

`[self addDefaultToolbar:field]`

But then again adding this method everywhere I need seems a bit 'dirty' (maybe this is not clear enough, `self` implies that within the controller there's a method called `addDefaultToolBar`).

So this is what I tried:

I made a nice folder, an header and an `.m` file. In the header I put this:

```
#ifndef UIUtils_h
#define UIUtils_h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIUtils : NSObject

-(void)addDefaultToolbar:(UITextField *)field;

@end

#endif /* UIUtils_h */
```

And in the `.m` file I put this:

```
#import "UIUtils.h"

@implementation UIUtils

-(void)addDefaultToolbar:(UITextField *)field{

    UIToolbar *textFieldToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    [textFieldToolbar sizeToFit];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneClick)];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [textFieldToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexSpace, doneButton, nil] animated:NO];
    field.inputAccessoryView = textFieldToolbar;
}

-(void)doneClick
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
}

@end
```

And then I call this from where I need it, like this:

```
#import "UIUtils.h"

UIUtils *utils = [[UIUtils alloc] init];
[utils addDefaultToolbar:field];
```

Now, unfortunately, the button doesn't work. The keyboard should be dismissed but it isn't. Secondly, I have no idea if I am doing this right.

How do I do this properly?

Edit:

Further research indicates that the `doneClick` method is not being called at all. It does work if I add `doneClick` to the viewController, but this kinda defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a toolbar that takes care of its own button press. You can create one of those.

```
@interface MYDefaultToolBar : UIToolbar
@end

@implementation MYDefaultToolBar

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [self initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
    if (self) {
        [self sizeToFit];
        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                                    target:self action:@selector(doneClick)];
        UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                                   target:self action:nil];
        [self setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexSpace, doneButton, nil] animated:NO];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)doneClick
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
}

@end
```

Then you want to be able to add it to text fields. I'd probably recommend doing that by hand:

```
textField.inputAccessoryView = [MYDefaultToolBar new];
```

This is very clear that it's modifying the inputAccessoryView (so if something else in the same code *also* modifies the inputAccessoryView, it'll be more obvious that there's a conflict). But you can also do this with a category, particularly if it were more complex.

```
@interface UITextField (AddDefaultToolBar)
- (void)my_addDefaultToolBar;
@end

@implementation UITextField (AddDefaultToolBar)

- (void)my_addDefaultToolBar {
    self.inputAccessoryView = [MYDefaultToolBar new];
}
```

Or you could modify `-[MYDefaultToolBar init]` to take a text field, and add itself.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks